# How would you find the maximum number a string has been repeated consecutively in a list?

Tags: python, algorithm

Say for example a list looks like this:

```
['ABC', 'ABC', 'XYZ', 'ABC', 'ABC', 'ABC']
```

And you pass in `'ABC'`
It should return the number `3`, since the maximum number of times `'ABC'` has repeated consecutively is `3`.
How would you go about doing this?

I've tried iterating through the list checking if the index is `'ABC'`, and if the next index is `'ABC'`, but this makes finding the maximum number almost impossible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter), which groups consecutive elements. By providing no key function, it groups equal elements.

We need to use `sum(1 for _ in v)` to get the length of the run (since it is an iterable rather than a list, we can't use `len`), and `max` to get the biggest length.

```py
from itertools import groupby

def longest_run_of(lst, element):
    return max(sum(1 for _ in v) for k, v in groupby(lst) if k == element)
```

Example:

```py
>>> longest_run_of(lst, 'ABC')
3
>>> longest_run_of(lst, 'XYZ')
1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
from itertools import groupby

x=['ABC', 'ABC', 'XYZ', 'ABC', 'ABC', 'ABC']

y=dict(sorted([(gr, len(list(val))) for gr, val in groupby(x, lambda el: el)], key=lambda el: el[1]))
```

It will return `dict` of maximal consecutive occurrences per element - so to get it for `ABC` just do:

```py
>> y["ABC"]
3
```

In short what's happening there - `groupby` will group consecutive occurrences together.

`len(list(val))` will count them.

Next we sort them to get the elements with highest number of consecutive occurrences at the end.

Then we convert to `dict` - leveraging the fact, that in case of multiple occurrences of the same key - `dict` always takes the last one, which thanks to sorting will always be the one with highest number of occurrences.